# Realizing Master Detail pattern in windows universal app

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, master-detail

I am stuck (StuckExchange). I need to do windows universal app. it should have some pages and one top bar and one side menu, same for all pages. As I understand I should use SplitView and master/details pattern (or am I wrong, and it is better way to make one top bar and side menu for many pages?). I did the part with SplitView, but the part with MasterDetails seems too hard for me to understand for now (I am new in windows universal and in c#).

Please help me! How should I realize master/details pattern in my issue? Can you suggest some simple code example, with only 2 pages to change, just to understand how in works, for a starting point?

I need to make something like this: (1 is before pushing hamburger button, 2 is after, and pages content should be different, accoarding what we push in side menu).[image]

Page context is not static text or smth, it is another view page with different buttons and other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split View is a nice starting point if the side-menu (hamburger menu) is what you want.

- Diederik Krols provided a [Sample Implementation on GitHub](https://github.com/XamlBrewer/UWP-SplitView-Sample)
- And there is also [SpitView Guide video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Developers-Guide-to-Windows-10-Preview/05) on channel 9.
- A full menu implementation on [Jerry Nixons blog](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2015/04/implementing-hamburger-button-with.html?m=1).

Comment: Thank you Kai!  But Split View is what I've done. What I can't understand - is how to use this top menu whith this SplitView as a Master in Master Detail pattern.

Comment: Jerry Nixon did a full implementation for a menu. I added his blog to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the Master/Detail template for a Windows Universal App - it does all the work resizing and reconfiguring for different devices and orientations:

[Windows Universal Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlMasterDetail)

it's not hard to modify for your own purposes.